# Generic iterator for an interface and its subclasses and its types and subtypes

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism

As the title says, I am trying to design a custom data structure `SearchTree` that would need to be `Iterable` over the entries such as `SearchTree.Entry<K, V>`. A `SearchTree` itself is just an interface.

What I want to do is to have that any class that implements `SearchTree<K, V>` with it's own subtypes of `K` and `V` is also able to implement the iterator as defined in a `SearchTree<K, V>` interface.

**SearchTree.java**

```
public interface SearchTree<K extends Comparable<? super K>, V> extends Iterable<SearchTree.Entry<K, V>> {

    static interface Entry<K, V> {

        K getKey(); 

        V getValue();

        void setValue(V value);
    }
}
```

And now suppose I have a class that implements the interface.

**BST.java**

```
public class BST<K extends Comparable<? super K>, V> implements SearchTree<K, V> {

    @Override
    public Iterator<Entry<K, V>> iterator() {
        // return some bst specific iterator
    }
}
```

**BSTNode.java**

```
public class BSTNode<K extends Comparable<? super K>, V> implements SearchTree.Entry<K, V> { // ...
}
```

Now, obviously, the `BST Iterator` should iterate over `BSTNode` objects, so it would make sense to declare it as something like:

**BSTIterator.java**

```
public class BSTIterator<K extends Comparable<? super K>, V> implements Iterator<BSTNode<K, V>> {
}
```

But now back to the problem from `BST.java` where the instance of `BSTIterator` should be returned as something like:

**BST.java**

```
public class BST<K extends Comparable<? super K>, V> implements SearchTree<K, V> {

    @Override
    public Iterator<Entry<K, V>> iterator() {
        return new BSTIterator<>();
    }
}
```

And now this doesn't work: **Can not infer type arguments for BSTIterator<>**.
Is there any sensible way to work around this problem, so that I can have a generic iterator in my interface, and a return concrete iterator implementations from the classes implementing the `SearchTree` in such manner that the generic types can also be subclassed?

Comment: Drop the `? super` from `Comparable<? super K>`. It doesn't ever make sense to compare an object to an instance of its supertype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close.  Your iterator `BSTIterator` must implement `Iterator<SearchTree.Entry<K, V>>` instead of `Iterator<BSTNode<K, V>>`.  I think it is because the type of your returned iterator has to guarantee it is any `Entry<K, V>`, not specifically `BSTNode`.

```
public class BSTIterator<K extends Comparable<? super K>, V> 
    implements Iterator<SearchTree.Entry<K, V>> {
    // ...
}

public class BST<K extends Comparable<? super K>, V> 
    implements SearchTree<K, V> {

    @Override
    public Iterator<SearchTree.Entry<K, V>> iterator() {
        return new BSTIterator<>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few of ways to approach this.

---

The most straightforward way is what [Neil describes in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46808295/3788176). But this is throwing away type information: for example if you wanted to use `BSTIterator` directly, you'd need to cast the elements back to `BSTNode`s if you want to use them as such.

---

The hacky (but actually entirely safe) approach is to note that there are no consumer methods on `Iterator<T>`: you can only ever get a value from it via `get()` (or check if there's another element, or remove the previously-got element).

As such, it is entirely safe to use an `Iterator<SubclassOfT>` as an `Iterator<T>`. Java's type system doesn't know that it's safe, so you have to cast:

```
return (Iterator<SearchTree.Entry<K, V>>) (Iterator<?>) new BSTIterator<K, V>();
```

and add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`.

---

The gross-in-a-different-way way to do this is to make the `SearchTree` implement iterable over an upper-bounded type:

```
public interface SearchTree<K extends Comparable<K>, V> 
    extends Iterable<? extends SearchTree.Entry<K, V>>
```

This is a bit gross because now the `iterator()` method will return an `Iterator<? extends SearchTree.Entry<K, V>>`: you're stuck with that `?`.

It is claimed by Josh Bloch in *Effective Java 2nd Ed* that if users of your API ever have to care about wildcards, you've designed it wrong. (Item 28, specifically page 137, if you've got a copy to hand).

---

Another way of doing it is to explicitly add a type variable for the type of the element in the `Iterator`:

```
public interface SearchTree<K extends Comparable<K>, V, T extends SearchTree.Entry<K, V>> 
    extends Iterable<T>
```

Now you can declare your `BST` as:

```
public class BST<K extends Comparable<K>, V> 
    implements SearchTree<K, V, BSTNode<K, V>>
```

This conveys the most type information, but I wouldn't claim this is absolutely better, because having 3 type variables whenever you declare a variable holding a `SearchTree` is just generic clutter, especially as the third will often contain the first and second again, e.g.

```
SearchTree<String, Integer, ? extends SearchTree.Entry<String, Integer>>
```

---

There's no super-great-clean option here. Personally, I'd go with the first, hacky option, because a) it really is safe! b) the hack is hidden inside the implementing class.